# How to check if nested object is descendant of another object not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following object.  What I would like to do is come up with a function that would specify if the given object is a descendant of a parent by the id.  For example, I'd like to do this: lodash is welcomed.

```
isThisDescendant(7,1) //true
isThisDescendant(1,7) //false
isThisDescendant(7,3) //false
isThisDescendant(3,2) //true

object = {
    children : [
        {
            name: 'a',
            id: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    id: 2,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'c',
                            id: 3,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'cc',
                            id: 4,
                            children: []
                        }                       
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'ba',
                    id: 6,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'c',
                            id: 8,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'cd',
                            id: 7,
                            children: []
                        }                       
                    ]
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'bb',
            id: 10,
            children: []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `id` should be a unique value but from what I see it's not (code smell!). There are two instances with the `id` `3`. How do you handle that case?

Comment: @KingKongFrog What have you tried? You should provide code that you tried and what is not working, rather than asking for a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create recursive function that will use `forEach` loop on arrays and also check if first parameter exists after second parameter is seen on any level.

```js
var object = {"children":[{"name":"a","id":1,"children":[{"name":"b","id":2,"children":[{"name":"c","id":3,"children":[]},{"name":"cc","id":4,"children":[]}]},{"name":"ba","id":6,"children":[{"name":"c","id":8,"children":[]},{"name":"cd","id":7,"children":[]}]}]},{"name":"bb","id":3,"children":[]}]}


function isThisDescendant(a, b) {
  var r = false;

  function f(a, b, data = object, p = false) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      data.forEach(function(o) {
        if (p && a == o.id) r = true;
        else f(a, b, o.children, !p ? b == o.id : p)
      })
    } else f(a, b, data.children, p)
  }
  f(a, b)
  return r
}

console.log(isThisDescendant(7, 1)) //true
console.log(isThisDescendant(1, 7)) //false
console.log(isThisDescendant(7, 3)) //false
console.log(isThisDescendant(3, 2)) //true
```

Comment: Isn't forEach a very expensive approach considering that you could also exit early when a match is found? True, the tree os very small but since the id's are unique, I don't see why you would like to traverse all children

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit overly verbose, but with some input paremeters you could do it like this

```js
function findNodeById( branch, id ) {
  if (!branch) {
    return null;
  }
  if (branch.id === id) {
    return branch;
  }
  for (let child of branch.children) {
    let result = findNodeById( child, id );
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

function isThisDescendant(tree, childId, parentId ) {
  const parent = findNodeById( tree, parentId );
  if (!parent) {
    return false;
  }
  const child = findNodeById( parent, childId );
  return child !== null;
}

const branch = {
    children : [
        {
            name: 'a',
            id: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    id: 2,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'c',
                            id: 3,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'cc',
                            id: 4,
                            children: []
                        }                       
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'ba',
                    id: 6,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'c',
                            id: 8,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'cd',
                            id: 7,
                            children: []
                        }                       
                    ]
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'bb',
            id: 10,
            children: []
        }
    ]
};
console.log(isThisDescendant(branch, 7,1)); //true
console.log(isThisDescendant(branch, 1,7)) //false
console.log(isThisDescendant(branch, 7,3)) //false
console.log(isThisDescendant(branch, 3,2)) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions but to be efficient it requires certain assumptions:

1. Is this a one-time thing or it needs to be constantly queried?

   If it is a one-time operation, then you can probably get away with doing a simple breadth first search to look for the parent, then check to see if its children contain the `id` you are looking for. This is O(n).

   If it is not, then you should build a lookup table `(id, instance)`, then use that table to look up your parent and do the checking. This is more or less O(1) to O(log n) given that the children size is way less than the size of the whole set.
2. Are the `children` arrays sorted?

   If the arrays are sorted, once you have the parent instance you can perform a binary search on the children array to further optimize it.

Comment: 1) one time thing and 2) they are not sorted.

Comment: @KingKongFrog Then it's simple, just perform any searching algorithm such as BFS or DFS (depends on the average structure of your tree) and look for the parent, then check if any child has the `id` that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to two steps here - crawling the tree to find the "container", and then crawling down from the container to find the descendent.

```js
const object = {
    children : [
        {
            name: 'a',
            id: 1,
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'b',
                    id: 2,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'c',
                            id: 3,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'cc',
                            id: 4,
                            children: []
                        }                       
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'ba',
                    id: 6,
                    children: [
                        {
                            name: 'c',
                            id: 8,
                            children: []
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'cd',
                            id: 7,
                            children: []
                        }                       
                    ]
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'bb',
            id: 10,
            children: []
        }
    ]
}

function isThisDescendant( descendentId, containerId, root = object, foundContainer = false ) {
   if ( root.id === descendentId && foundContainer ) return true; //found it inside the container
   if ( root.id === descendentId && !foundContainer ) return false; //we found the descendent before the container

   //recurse down to children
   const newFoundContainer = foundContainer || root.id === containerId;
   const childResults = root.children.map( 
      child => isThisDescendant( descendentId, containerId, child, newFoundContainer )
   );
   return or( childResults );  //return true if any of the children hits
}

//returns true if any items in the array are true
function or( values ) {
   return Boolean( values.filter( Boolean ).length );
}

    
console.log( isThisDescendant(7,1) ); //true
console.log( isThisDescendant(1,7) ); //false
console.log( isThisDescendant(7,3) ); //false
console.log( isThisDescendant(3,2) );//true
```

A few notes:

- Performance will be very poor on large trees - use indexing to speed up (if each object knows its parent, you can walk up the tree much more easily)
- We use default parameter values so that the first call to the recursive function always starts with at the top (`root = object`) and with the `foundContainer` variable as `false` so we look for the container first
- Because this branches out, I've avoided storing `foundContainer` as persistent state - it's best to work out what to pass down each time and keep your recursion "pure" (free of state/side effects)

Answer (score 0):

This problem involves a common problem: finding a node in a tree "like" structure. This always involves recursion.

You could write a function `isDescendant(rootObj, valueA, valueB)`. It would look something like this:

```
function isDescendant(rootObj, parentId, childId) {
  const parentNode = findChildren(rootObj, parentId); // Find the parent node
  if (!parentNode) return false;
  return !!findChildren(parentNode, childId); // Find the child node
}

function findChildren(obj, id) {
  if (obj.id === id) return obj;
  if (obj.children) return obj.children.find(c => findChildren(c, id));
}
```